# JavaFX - UTF-8 in Webpage?

Tags: java, javafx, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I do have a `WebView` in JavaFX, i'd like to use "ä", "ö", "ü" and tons of other UTF-8 characters, but it doesn't work since the charset in the application is wrong, settings it at the start per .bat / .sh file isn't an option for me tho. What am i supposed to do?
I am using the meta charset attribute provided by HTML 5 in the WebView

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

i also tried the new (HTML5 compatible) way

`<meta charset='UTF-8'>`

Even though i am doing that it looks like that: `Kï¿½se`, it was supposed to be `Käse`.

Eclipse starts the application with UTF-8 charset by default.
But outside of eclipse the system / runtime default is used.
So what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` to write and read the UTF-8 encoded data, instead of `PrintWriter` and `BufferedReader`, everything works correctly.